# Getting an input element value inside TR table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have an html table called #DimensionAttributes whose columns are as follows:

```
<td><input type="text" name="txtLEName" value="@attribute.Key" /></td>
```

I intentionally wanted to maintain the name of the input element static. There can be multiple rows bound to this table. How do I loop through each row and find out the input elements value using the ID. The reason I wanted to use ID is because there can be multiple columns that would come soon in this table. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use selector, perhaps:

```
$("input[name='txtLEName']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first all, an ID must be unique, instead used class. Or if you eagerly wanted to use ID, try selecting by this :

Suppose you have this two element with same ID name :

```
<td><input type="text" name="txtLEName" value="@attribute.Key" id="hello"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtLEName" value="@attribute.Key" id="hello"/></td>
```

Then your selector should be :

```
$('[id="hello"]')
```

Or another way, if you want to increment the ID name like :

```
<td><input type="text" name="txtLEName" value="@attribute.Key" id="hello1"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtLEName" value="@attribute.Key" id="hello2"/></td>
```

As you dont know how many of element since the element created dynamically, then you can select it using this :

```
 $('[id^="hello"]') // find the element ID name start with `hello`
```

Comment: Would this give only the first one and not the second one?

Comment: @Pekka Both are returned

Comment: I would still prefer not give him suggestion on keeping same id using a class is feasible in this problem.just use closest tr

Comment: Thanks So I wanted to search this within a TR tab in the table with id DimensionAttributes. So  I should loop through and also if I loop through the first row will be the header where I won't find a match using the ID. May I know how to implement the same?

Comment: @Pekka yes, should be like that. Use class as possible.

Comment: @SARAVAN just target the child itself like this `$('#DimensionAttributes [id="hello"]')`, as this only loop through the matched selector

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop thru each row, why not write something like this:

```
$("#DimensionAttributes tr input[name='txtLEName']").each(function(){ 
    //Your code here:
    //$(this).val()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $rows = $('#table').find("tr:not(:eq(0))");
$rows.each(function () {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    var val = $tds.find(':text').val();
    console.log(val);



})
```

Assuming you have 1 input text each row you can select the table id find the tr and iterate and find td with input and get the value

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mp3bkumq/)